# Undeclared identifier xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, class, undeclared-identifier

I just wondering on how do i go about with this it seems like all the forums that i went to do the same as what i did but however when i run.. there is this error.. need help

another thing that i wanna ask is about the int main()

can i creating a file name mission.cpp
can i put the int main() there or must i do something else

This is the error that i received..

[image: Undeclared Variable]

This is my header file[image]

Comment: Why are you recursively including the cpp in the h file??

Comment: As @MarcoA. says, you need to delete `#include "LocationData.cpp"` from your header file.

Comment: I already did the top one is .cpp file and the bottom one is .h

Comment: Read carefully: *you need to delete `#include "LocationData.cpp"` from your header (.h) file.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lethal combination  of include-guards + including the header file in the cpp file + including the cpp file into the header file is leaving undefined stuff.

Solution: delete the `#include "LocationData.cpp"` line in your header file.